# some pages are very slow when not defaultlanguage

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x, tx-news

When I request a page in another language the serverresponse is very slow. In the defaultLanguage it is fast.

```
www.domain.com --> is fast
www.domain.com/?L=1 --> is slow
www.domain.com/?L=2 --> is slow
```

Only Pages that have multilanguage (singletree) configured are slow. But the content is an 1:1 copy of the defaultLanguage for now. And also only the pages that have the tx_news plugin listview are slow.

How can I debug this? What could cause that?

Comment: You can try to enable the admin panel, it shows some profiling info. Here's how  to enable it: http://www.pi-phi.de/74.html.

Comment: Must probably it is tx_news where translations generate bad queries what will overload mysql (tail your mysql log).

If you use content_fallback on your news pages, try setting it to strict. 

I thought this was already fixed in the latest version of tx_news but this bug report is still open:
https://forge.typo3.org/issues/58574

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See rob-ot comment.

The querys run very slow when there are translations. As workaround I use different folders for each language and set the startingpoint with typoscript when an alternative language is called.